# Conditional class values using ngClass - Angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I want to apply multiple class but there is some difference here compared to other questions of Stackoverflow.

I have to dynamically assign `icon` class and also `'not-selected'`

**component.ts**

```
list = [ { name: 'Name1', icon: 'icon_1' }, { name: 'Name2', icon: 'icon_2' } ]
```

```
<div *ngFor="let data of list" 
    [ngClass]="{ 'some_icon' : true , 'not-selected': selectedOperation?.name !== operation.name }"> 
    {{data.name}} 
</div>
```

I can see `some_icon` but what I need is dynamically assign `data.icon` too. something like:

```
<div *ngFor="let data of list" 
    [ngClass]="{ data.icon , 'not-selected': selectedVal?.name !== data.name }"> 
    {{data.name}} 
</div>
```

but this one is not the correct syntax. What am I missing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

while using `[ngClass]` [you have 3 options](https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass), one giving the object that way the keys will be the class name if the value returns true (truthy). the others are regular string and list of arrays but you cannot use a combination of them. For your case, you can use a combination of `class` and `[ngClass]` this way you can also use static class names in the HTML as well.

```
class="{{iconName}} static-class-name" [ngClass]="{'redClass': useRedClass}"
```

you must define your data similar to the below one.

```
export class AppComponent {
  title = "CodeSandbox";
  iconName = 'icon1';
  useRedClass = true;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try with `[class]` input.

```
<div *ngFor="let data of list" [class]="data.icon"
    [ngClass]="{'not-selected': selectedVal?.name !== data.name }"> 
    {{data.name}} 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

When the dynamic event happens that will trigger your icons to be changed, assign your list again

```
private myDynamicChangeHandler = () => {
    this.list = [ { name: 'Name1', icon: this.useIcon1 ? 'icon_1' : 'icon_2' }, { name: 'Name2', icon: this.useIcon1 ? 'icon_1' : 'icon_2' } ]`
};
```

Comment: I can have `n`  number of `icon` with a `list` which has length `n`

Answer (score 0):

I have had success adding dynamic icon classes to the 'normal' `class` property string with string interpolation and also with pipes. Maybe it works for you too.
Remember to add spaces between the class names

```html
<div *ngFor="let data of list" 
    [class]="{{data.icon}} + ' ' +'otherDivClass redIconColorClass'"> 
    {{data.name}} 
</div>
```

Comment: probably He cant deal with conditional class here.